# Life On The Surface

Tags: discussion

**TV show**

If I ask myself the question, If BSE was a mini series what would it look like?  SE sites are somewhat a pyramid scheme, would we set it ancient Egypt, who would play Duarte?

IMHO one of the best tv series is HBO's Deadwood, initially written to be in ancient Rome, it found its way to the *"Wild West"* since HBO had recently screened *"Rome"*.  It has marshals and sheriffs, deputies, [gunslingers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), [whores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281787/it-s-time-to-retire-the-term-rep-whore), .. I'm leaning towards some steampunkish western setting.

[image]

**The Creators**

The Gods of our show, who without there would be no BSE.

*In no particular order, a little chicken and egg*

- SE  The site is part of the Stack Exchange Universe, participants often share their time in *Stackoverflow*,  *Seasoned Advice*, *Are there really Aliens?*
- The devs Those gods who work tirelessly to create Blender. Like all gods their choices are questioned, why Z up, why isn't cube 1 x 1 x 1, why not use degrees for angle

Gods from both often "walk among us". Keep in mind for any church or religious characters in the show.

**Territories**

The site is split into a number of territories.  As a noob to our first SE Universe we are given one sheckle and the opportunity to stake our claim with a new question in up to 5 territories or answer any unprotected question.

**Sheckles**

The monetary system here is very simple. As soon as you have 15 sheckles you can hand out sheckles (upvote) without limit. If a claim (question) is a mine, think of a sheckle like any of the dirt you dig out. The "better" the mine, the more gets thrown in. Even so, high sheckle mines are soon deep below the surface. Many believe the  SE gods have made perhaps one of the worst search engines ever to keep us on the surface.  The HNQ Circus tours the surface, for claims to
rain down sheckles upon.

**Pioneers**

The first Noobs to set foot on BSE and stake their claims. Like all pioneers most are now long gone.

**The Noob Hordes**

As the site "matures" the Noob Hordes become larger and larger. This is where a lot of the show plays out.  Due to a number of Noob rights violations the SE Gods drew up some protections [CoC]

**Marshals**

Voted in, for life, to control in particular the Noob Horde.

**Sheriffs and their Deputies**

If you have a gold badge in a  territory you can DupeHammer or by other means necessary try and keep the Noobs to the "rules".  For those that don't know me, I have a gold badge in the dual territory of Python-Scripting. Our rules are a bit different from those in Maudlin (aka Modelling) Territory.

Deputies help the Marshals and Sheriffs keep to the SE rules. Deputies often become Sheriffs.

**The Good the Bad and the Ugly**

Like the Chinese in ancient times, or more recently the US, do we  build a wall at the border of our territory. Can it resist the horde? Remember the Alamo?

Things you see and hear at the border.

- Bleary eyed sleep deprived gunslingers
- Addicts
- Calls of "*So, I wanna*", *"Show us your blend!"* echoing
- The same Shot down low quality Noob claim reincarnate
- Sheckles flying every where when the HNQ Circus is in town.
- An unwanted intruder, selling spam, de-sheckled faster than a rocket full of monkeys

**The question.**

Your take on what role you would play, the other  characters (by type please not by name) , possible scenarios... or maybe you would set the show completely differently.

Comment: This is possibly one of the most fun uses of our meta I have ever seen. Not really within the rules but I suppose there's no real harm. This actually made me laugh, this community can surprise me some times. I'll answer it later :D

Comment: Hopefully it is taken in the spirit intended. My dry/dark SOH was looking for a "fun" way to cool down some of the friction on the surface. Funny how all communities mimic RL to some extent. My speyes tell me _@voter fraud_ has reared its ugly head again.

Answer (score 10):

Not long ago the Monica wars took a heavy toll across all Stack Exchangia, affecting most areas of the universe. Many marshals died, some resigned due to post traumatic stress, others went into hyper-sleep for prolonged periods, awakening occasionally when the need is most dire.

This left us with the current generation of marshals, rookies in the eyes of the old veterans, inexperienced in many ways. They weren't here in the old days when the land of Blender Stack Exchange was created, they didn't help create the world or shape it into what it is today.

They try their best to keep the planet running and the rules respected non the less, with what little knowledge was passed down from the old ones, to shape the future into something better.

Many impending dangers loom in the distance threatening the land.

### The threat of the donut wielders

Donut wielders pop up everywhere these days, threatening local wild life and way of life with their intrusive high calorie, high sugar, low value, diabetes inducing samey junk food.
Their numbers increase daily making them a foe to be reckoned with.

### Help Vampires

They come at night and strike silently in the dark, stealing precious energy from our users with incessant questioning at the minor of inconveniences. They don't care for the common well being, and bring no value to the game, relying on others for answers giving little sheckles back. They get most of their nourishment from stray whores and sheckle-farmers trying to make a living from whatever they can scrap.

### Allies

We do have some strong allies that defend the land at all costs.

BatFinger is the master of the old order of mages wielding the ancient power of coding. They are skilled in the art of scripting with the old language of the Serpent.

This not only grants them the prime access to contact the dev Gods by speaking the language of the divinity, it allows them to make quick work of hordes of noobs and even uber-noobs with bare coding skills.

With two fortresses in the lands of both Python and Scripting they control the borders and tirelessly defend the land using the power of Python scripting.

There are many other allies and vigilantes who on a daily basis tirelessly help manage the [growing backlog of flag reports](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review) that reach the marshal stations.

We have gained and lost many other friends along the way, like [Ray Mairlot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/241/ray-mairlot) the Gate Keeper. He was adamant in keeping the territory borders clear and well defined, tirelessly tagging questions, and keeping tabs on a highly organized and coherent system of tags for keeping noob trespassers in check.

Some marshals and users like to cross universes from time to time to [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) realm, a land of vices, gluttony, excess, for an occasional respite from the demanding work of keeping the land of Susane the monkey safe.

Comment: Fortunately none of those dang varmint **donutters** come into python-scripting territory.  Have  been mostly safe from the anvil plague too.

Comment: I even forgot about the anvil haha, good one

Comment: I'm going to ask how to script a donut + icing using python just for @batFINGER

Answer (score 9):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| [image] Clint Eastwood playing ‘Blondie’ in ‘The Good, the Bad and the Ugly’ | [image: N]ot exactly radiating with warmth, sometimes rough to interact with, this epic character has a heart of gold, helping those in need even at the worst odds and the highest of stakes. Twelve shooters and a sniper on the roof? You say ‘impossible’, yet he single–handedly disposes of all of them, and when you think it couldn’t get any better, turns out he managed with just two six–shooters without the need to reload even once! Considering usually few (alive) men witness those great deeds and the hero gets rewarded with merely a *sheckle* or two, it makes his accumulated wealth even more impressive… |
|  |  |
| [image] Sharon Stone playing ‘Ellen’ in ‘The Quick and the Dead’ | [image: D]on’t make the mistake of underestimating her. Just because she has no reputation, doesn’t mean she has no experience. You might be surprised if you investigate the archives for her accounts outside ʙꜱᴇ; even if you find nothing there, she still might have extraordinary deeds outside of *Stack Exchangia*… |
|  |  |
| [image] Sean Connery playing ‘Allan Quatermain’ in ‘The League of Extraordinary Gentlemen’ | [image: H]e achieved everything he could in the land of ʙꜱᴇ. Perhaps one day he will return, when the *Exchangians* need him the most. For now, we can enjoy his legacy, both what we see: great answers, policies and inspired community, as well as what cannot be seen: conflicts averted, villains banished, damage avoided… |
|  |  |
| [image] Charlie Cox playing ‘Tristan Thorn’ in ‘Stardust’ (2007) | [image: U]nlike the outsider, he indeed is a noob. But this one learns really fast. He came to ʙꜱᴇ to get help, but stayed to help others. It seems like yesterday, that he didn’t know a thing, and now he’s finding himself correcting the veterans. If his luck won’t fail him, he may age to become one of the above archetypes… |
|  | ## … |
| [image]<sup>Jamie Foxx playing the title character in ‘Django Unchained’</sup> | [image: N]ot much can be said in general about such people. Everyone is different, and so that's what they share — they are different than everyone else. And yes, every human being is different, but not all so **flamboyantly**! People say there are no wrong questions, but if there is one, someone extravagant is asking it; you may discover that *“there’s a method to his madness”*, and if not, maybe at least get provoked to think outside the box… |
|  |  |
| [image] ‘Droid IG-11’ dubbed by Taika Waititi in ‘Mandalorian’ | [image: T]ireless, but not mindless; turns out with enough gears the mechanism becomes complex enough to develop consciousness. Unlike what you expect from a robot, it doesn’t blindly follow the rules: be it off–topic, two questions in one, a duplicate or poor research, it responds to the call for rescue. It doesn’t know arrogance and will not look down on simple problems as unworthy of its time. Its systematicity is a crucial foundation of the ʙꜱᴇ society… |
|  |  |
| [image] Mel Brooks playing ‘Governor Le Petomane’ in ‘Blazing Saddles’ | [image: H]ow is it possible this incompetent idiot amassed so much wealth‽ Looking into the archives, you can count on fingers of one hand when he tried to help someone, always with embarrassing results. It looks like the secret of his success is he was never afraid to ask for help and was helped over and over again. Perhaps by asking his stupid questions he provoked so many great answers, that some credit was due… |
|  |  |
| [image] John Wayne playing ‘Sheriff John T. Chance’ in ‘Rio Bravo’ (1959) | [image: S]heriff’s badge is not just an insignia of power. It’s a symbol of respect of ʙꜱᴇ citizens. Despite what media might make you believe, sheriffs spend little time fighting villains, and a lot on rigorous task of keeping the society functional. Someone new in the community might even think his sheriff is able to do only that, but every now and then the guardian of law steps in to answer a distress and shows his true power… |
|  |  |
| [image] Kenneth Branagh playing ‘Dr. Arliss Loveless’ in ‘The Wild Wild West’ | [image: F]ortunately, there aren’t really any villains in the ʙꜱᴇ. Yes, sometimes someone will have a bad day and act in a bad faith, however, people in conflict eventually cool down. Still, we all meet this character in our worst nightmares, the embodiment of human viciousness, Frankenstein’s monster of all possible malice: he downvotes good work because he hates the person behind it; tries to insult others, driven by arrogance; breaks the rules and peskilly keeps reverting the fix by a sheriff; blows off steam on poor newcomers, who come in his way. Who knows, maybe such people would be swarming the ʙꜱᴇ land if not for the hard work of sheriffs who usually nip the fire in the bud… |

Comment: This has to be the most beautifully composed post of the whole Stack Exchangia, complete with drop caps and gothic fonts. Kudos for that! We could make an RPG out of this, I can almost pinpoint specific users behind every archetype.

Comment: Bravo. You truly have a way with words, sir, just as with noodles :))

Comment: Thanks for this. Totally OTT, love it. Apologies for not commenting earlier. IMO would have made the gunslinger droid a permanent fixture (side-kick) best actor in it.. except for maybe Olyphant. @DuarteFarrajotaRamos funny you mention that, it was a toss up between TV show and MMORPG  in some ways the latter fits better, same end game. .. _ie_ keep going or quit.  That post I flagged as VLQ -> Marshal badge. Was surprised to see I'm only number 8.  Think the other 499 were not an answer.